# Generate script from database in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am developing a C # application and I want a window that displays all existing tables in the database the user make the choice of tables that want to recreate in a new database in a sql compact, some tables must contain the initial information and the other just the structure of the table.

Is there any help to recreate this table?

I think to generate the script of the existing table (*.sql) and creating table from file to the new database, but I do not know how to make a query to generate a sql table.

PS: the existing table is in sqlserver, and I want to create a table in sqlcompact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following views:

```
Information_Schema.TABLES
Information_Schema.COLUMNS
Information_Schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
Information_Schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
Information_Schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
```

I don't have the code to hand (sorry) but I've used these before to recreate a table definition based off the database's own metadata in pure TSQL and there's no reason it couldn't be done in C# within the application just as well. Join them up together, declare a string for your final definition and cursor through the results set to get all the fields in your table, building up the output. When you're done, return that to the client. For testing purposes compare the output of your code to what SSMS produces when you ask it to script creation of a table and hopefully you'll be able to get your table definitions recreated relatively quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SMO to do this.

[SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)

A quick example is here:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SMO/scriptdatabaseobjectswithsmo/2342/

Comment: thx for the link, I have change the StoredProcedure sourceSp = myDB.StoredProcedures["sp_testScript"]; by Table sourceSp = myDB.Tables["My_table"]; but I have to know how read the structure of table and his records

Comment: and the query of Table sourceSp = myDB.Tables["My_table"] don't make the PRIMARY KEY !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the [differences between Sql Server and Sql Server CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140.aspx) but you can use Sql Server Management Studio to generate script for tables, procedures etc. Right click to database then Tasks > Generate Scripts.

As I know most of the not supported features are queries, procedures, views...

Comment: I know that Management Studio can do that but I want do it from c# ... from the application : user have the choice of tables to export

Comment: @Akrem: You can copy data with SqlBulkCopy but I'm not sure about table structure http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlBulkCopy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NHibernate for data access, they have a nice SchemaExport tool that will work for all databases supported by NHibernate (not just SQL Server). Thus, your solution would be to list all mapped entities, let user pick the ones he wants, create a new configuration with selected entities and use SchemaExport to generate SQL in the dialect you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my scripting API/library to generate CREATE TABLE scripts in proper SQL Server Compact dialect. SMO cannot do that for you, it i targeted at various SQL Server versions.
http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com